# Android Proguard -android is not supported?

Tags: android, proguard

I add '-android' in my project's proguard-rules.pro file,but when I release my project,the Gradle Console gives the Warning:

```
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '-android' in line 31 of file '/Users/yushuifeng/workspace/cccx_app_3.0/app/proguard-rules.pro'
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
```

why?
I add this option because the official website says

> -android
>   Specifies that the processed class files are targeted at the Android platform. ProGuard then makes sure some features are compatible with Android. For example, you should specify this option if you are processing an Android application.

refs:https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#preverificationoptions

sorry I don't know how to format the text,so I can post my code in proguard-rules.pro file, just a standard proguard with an additional option

> -android

Comment: please post your proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: why did you add it? what did you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-ignorewarnings` in your `proguard-rules.pro` file, then clean & build your project.

Comment: I just want to know why this option is unknown to gradle,isn't it the suggest option in official website?

Answer (score 0):

The option `-android` was added in ProGuard 6.0. It is very likely that your standard gradle setup uses a different version of ProGuard. The version being used should be printed if you enable `-i` for your gradle build and possibly add `-verbose` to your proguard rules.